# Create a receipt for a user form submission

Tags: python, form-submit

There is a requirement that our users should complete and submit a form once a month. So, each month we should have a form that will contain data for the triplet (username, month, year). I want our users to be able to certify that they did actually submit the form for that particular month by creating a receipt for them. So, for each month there will be a report containing the data the user submitted along with the receipt. I don't want the users to be able to create that receipt by themselves though.

What I was thinking was to create a string that contained `username`, `month`, `year`, `secret_word` and give the **md5 hash** of that string to the users as their receipt. That way because the users won't have the secret word they won't be able to generate the md5 hash. However my users will probably complain when they see the complexity of that md5 hash. Also if the find out the secret word they will be able to create receipts for everybody.

Is there a standard way of doing what I ask ? Could you recommend me any other possible solutions  ?

I am using Python but some pseudocode or link to the appropriate methods would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Serafeim, your approach is very good for the situation. Here are some ideas of extending it:

1. Make sure that the secret_word (in hashing terms it is called **salt**) is long enough.
2. Make the end function a bit more complex, e.g.

   `hash = h(h(username) + month + year + h(salt))`
3. Use a bit more complex hash function, e.g. SHA1
4. Don't give the end user the whole hash value. E.g. md5 hex digest contains 32 digits, but it would be enough to have first 5-10 digits of the hash in the report.

**Updated:**

In case you have resources, generate a **random** salt per user. Then even if somehow a user will learn the salt and the hash function, it will be still useless for the others.

Comment: I could also convert the hex number to a 10 based number in order to present only 0-9 digits to the user and show (e.g) 12 of these to the user ...

Comment: Absolutely. That will look even less suspicious that a part of a hex digest.